# Mean and Variance Verification

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with the pdf

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x} &: 0 <x\\
0 &: \text{else}
\end{cases}$

and suppose we want to find the mean and variance.

First to find the mean,

$\mu=\int _0^{\infty }\:x\cdot f\left(x\right)dx=\int _0^{\infty }\:x\cdot \left(-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x}\right)dx=\int _0^{\infty }\:-2xe^{-2x}+2xe^{-x}dx=\frac{5}{2}$

and then to find the variance,

$\sigma^2(X)=E(X)^2-(E(X))^2$

$\quad \qquad=\int _0^{\infty }\:x^2\cdot \left(-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x}\right)dx-\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$

$\quad \qquad = \int _0^{\infty }\:-2x^2e^{-2x}+2x^2e^{-x}dx-\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$

$\quad \qquad =\frac{7}{2}-\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$

$\quad \qquad = -\frac{11}{4} =-2.75$

However this is obviously incorrect, as the variance shouldn't be negative. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Cheers! What a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the mean is incorrect, therefore making the variance calculation wrong.

Instead, the mean is $3/2$.  You can see this by observing that $2e^{-2x}$ is the density for an exponential distribution with mean $1/2$, and $e^{-x}$ is the density for an exponential distribution with mean $1$.  Therefore, the linear combination of these has mean $2(1) - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$.  Your second moment calculation is correct, so you would get a variance of $\frac{7}{2} - (\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit embarrassed that I made such a dumb mistake. Thanks again for clearing that up.